# vuejs-framework7 toolbar route

Tags: routes, vue.js, toolbar, html-framework-7

I am working on a app made with Framework7 and vuejs.

I have bottom toolbar but i have routing problem here.

here's my code

route.js

```
{
path: '/about/',
component: require('./assets/vue/pages/about.vue')}
```

main.vue

```
<div class="toolbar tabbar tabbar-labels">
  <div class="toolbar-inner">
    <a class="item-link tab-link" href="/about/">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      <span class="tabbar-label">Home</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

when i clicked the toolbar i get the error Cannot GET /about/.

but when i clicked same link from outside the toolbar, it works...

Someone have any idea or have a better solution?

Comment: This seems like it should be working. I'd try giving your `'/about/'` route a name property in its definition in the `route.js` file (like `name: 'about',`) and then using a `router-link` tag to generate the link to that named route via `<router-link :to="{ name: 'about' }">`

Comment: missing details: vue version, vue-router version, framework7 version.

Answer (score 0):

SPA project means all the pages are base on a same `uri`, distinguished by following '#', for example:

- http://yourdomain.com/#/home/
- http://yourdomain.com/#/about/

So all the pages are on uri '/',  `'/about' != '/#/about'`

You should use `<router-link to="/about">Go to About</router-link>` or use js code `router.push({ path: 'about' })`.

See [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html)